# nullpointerexception error while using cookies in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am getting nullpointerexception at if condition . How to resolve this error. My code and error decription is below.

error :An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

error occurs on this line:    if (Request.Cookies[name].Value != null)

```
  public void SetCookie(string name, string value, int expiration)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie;
        cookie = new HttpCookie(name);
        if (Request.Cookies[name].Value != null)
        {
            DeleteCookie(name);
        }
        else
        {
            cookie.Value = value;
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(expiration);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you know what a `NullReferenceException` actually means?

Comment: I think this error occurs when cookies not exist in browser .

Comment: Yes, in this case, that is almost certainly the case.  But what does that exception *mean*?  What is it saying about your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to the following:

```
 public void SetCookie(string name, string value, int expiration)
{
    if(Request.Browser.Cookies)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies[name] != null)
        {
            DeleteCookie(name);
        }

        HttpCookie cookie;
        cookie = new HttpCookie(name);
        cookie.Value = value;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(expiration);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
}
```